# Composition API losing variable reactivity

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, inertiajs

I am trying get array of ranks in **ranks_options** from the useForm helper but it's not tracking current array

Here is my code please check

```js
const form = useForm({
    name: null,
    ranks: [],
});

function addRanks() {
    form.ranks.push({ name: null, id:null});
}

ranks_options = form.ranks.map(function (value) {
    return value.name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html):

```js
const ranks_options = computed(() => form.ranks.map(value => value.name)
```

This will set `form.rank` as a dependency, and recompute its value when a dependency changes.